# ascii codec cant encode character u'\u2019' ordinal out of range(128)

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, arcgis, arcpy

Python 2.6, upgrading not an option

Script is designed to take fields from a arcgis database and create Insert oracle statements to a text file that can be used at a later date. There are 7500 records after 3000 records it errors out and says the problem lies at.

```
fieldValue = unicode(str(row.getValue(field.name)),'utf-8',errors='ignore')
```

I have tried seemly every variation of unicode and encode. I am new to python and really just need someone with experience to look at my code and see where the problem is.

```
import arcpy

#Where the GDB Table is located
fc = "D:\GIS Data\eMaps\ALDOT\ALDOT_eMaps_SignInventory.gdb/SignLocation"

fields = arcpy.ListFields(fc)
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)

#text file output
outFile = open(r"C:\Users\kkieliszek\Desktop\transfer.text", "w")


#insert values into table billboard.sign_inventory
for row in cursor:
 outFile.write("Insert into billboard.sign_inventory() Values (") 
 for field in fields:

    fieldValue = unicode(str(row.getValue(field.name)),'utf-8',errors='ignore')

    if row.isNull(field.name) or fieldValue.strip() == "" : #if field is Null or a Empty String print NULL
        value = "NULL"
        outFile.write('"' + value + '",')
    else: #print the value in the field
        value = str(row.getValue(field.name))
        outFile.write('"' + value + '",')

outFile.write("); \n\n ")


outFile.close()    # This closes the text file
```

Error Code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "tablemig.py", line 25, in <module>
  fieldValue = unicode(str(row.getValue(field.name)),'utf-8',errors='ignore')
 UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in    position 76: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: The error is coming from your call to 'str' on the value. Just call unicode on the row.getValue(...) directly.

Comment: I'm aware.. ```str(u'\u2019')``` results in ```UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)```

Comment: If the first non-ascii character (RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK) comes after 3000 records, I'd guess it's a data error.  Have you considered editing the input file?  Personally, I'd put the existing code in a try/except block to see how many rows give the error.  You don't have so much data that correcting it is not an option.  Of course, there are many considerations that you know about and I don't. :-)

Comment: unrelated: use raw-string literals `r''` for Windows paths (backslash may be special inside Python string literal otherwise).

Comment: “have tried seemly every variation of unicode and encode” → There's a guide to understanding this issue in the Python docs: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Answer (score 2):

Never call `str()` on a `unicode` object:

```
>>> str(u'\u2019')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

To write rows that contain Unicode strings in csv format, use [`UnicodeWriter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples) instead of formatting the fields manually. It should fix several issues at once.

Answer (score 1):

File TextWrappers make manual encoding/decoding unnecessary.

Assuming the result from the row is a Unicode, simply use the `io.open()` with the encoding attribute set to the required encoding.

For example:

```
import io

with io.open(r"C:\Users\kkieliszek\Desktop\transfer.text", "w", encoding='utf-8') as my_file:
    my_file(my_unicode)
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you need to decode/encode unicode/byte string instead of just calling `str` on it. So, if you have a byte string object, then you need to call encode on it to convert it into unicode object ignoring utf content. On the other hand, if you have `unicode` object, you need to call `decode` on it to convert it into `byte string` ignoring utf again. So, just use this function instead

```
import re

def remove_unicode(string_data):
    """ (str|unicode) -> (str|unicode)

    recovers ascii content from string_data
    """
    if string_data is None:
        return string_data

    if isinstance(string_data, str):
        string_data = str(string_data.decode('ascii', 'ignore'))
    else:
        string_data = string_data.encode('ascii', 'ignore')

    remove_ctrl_chars_regex = re.compile(r'[^\x20-\x7e]')

    return remove_ctrl_chars_regex.sub('', string_data)

fieldValue = remove_unicode(row.getValue(field.name))
```

It should fix the problem.